# What is the difference between an Instance and an Instance group

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gce-instance-group

I was wondering what the difference between an instance and an instance group are.

Can anyone explain the difference to me?

Why can we use Autoscaler with an instance group and not with a instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In GCE, An instance is a single virtual machine that you can customise (CPU, network, endpoint, disk, etc) and manage by you (shutdown, run, build with new image, etc)

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/

> An instance is a virtual machine hosted on Google's infrastructure.
>
> Instances can run the Linux images provided by Google, or any
>   customized versions of these images. You can also build and run images
>   of other operating systems.

While an instance group is a collection of the instances above, for management. i.e. I have two groups, slow instances and fast instances.

Autoscaler is something that you can use with Managed Instance Group. This a group that is created by Instance Manager using an instance template.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/

> A Compute Engine Autoscaler automatically adds or removes virtual
>   machines from a managed instance group based on increases or decreases
>   in load. This allows your applications to gracefully handle increases
>   in traffic and reduces cost when the need for resources is lower. You
>   just define the autoscaling policy and the autoscaler performs
>   automatic scaling based on the measured load.

Hope it helps.
Cheers.

Comment: I know that. I have read the google docs before asking.
But that still wondering for me. Because, the Autoscaler will be run with single instance. I don't understand why we can't?
This is the single method to do a personal instance running like app engine ? (scaling automatically)

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand your question. AutoScaler will run only a single instance if a single instance is enough to handle the workload. You can configure the workload threshold in Policy. Try lowering the threshold, and do a stress test, it should create more instances when it reached the threshold. AutoScaler has similar behaviour to AppEngine that it scales automatically, but also gives you the freedom of having your own virtual machine.

Comment: Ok, if I understand everything. the instance group can function as a single instance but not enverse?
In that case, why creates a single instance?

Comment: Simply, you don't always need to scale horizontally. For example, a primary/master instance don't need to scale horizontally if its purpose is only to schedule and prioritise tasks to slaves.